# Importing contacts and emails from Yahoo to Gmail

Tags: gmail, yahoo-mail, import

How do I import ALL contacts and emails from Yahoo to Gmail in one go, if there is no "Accounts/Import" tab?

Is there an easy work around?

Answer (score 2):

The `Account and Import` tab has disappeared (2009) and returned only `Accounts`. See the following two references from Google on how to export/import:

1. [Import email and contacts](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/164640?hl=en&from=117173&rd=1)
2. [Centralize mail from different accounts with Mail Fetcher](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/21289)